# PEAR module (HTTP_Request2) installed, but not recognized in php file?

Tags: php, pear, http-request2

I have HTTP_Request2 installed on my server; `pear list` shows it in the list of installed packages. But the following php file:

```
<?php

ini_set("include_path", '/path/to/php:' . ini_get("include_path"));

if (class_exists('HTTP_Request2')) {
    print("true");
} else {
    print("false");
}
```

...returns `false`. I've also tried replacing the `ini_set` line with

```
include '/path/to/php/HTTP/Request2.php';
```

...but I get the same result. Is there something I'm missing, or something else I can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply setting the include path doesn't implicitly give you access to the code. You need to either set the include path and then use relative includes:

```
ini_set("include_path", ...);
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
```

Or just use fully qualified includes:

```
require_once '/path/to/HTTP/Request2.php';
```

That said, HTTP_Request2 is kinda old and I'd instead recommend using something like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) via composer.

Comment: Thanks so much... that fixed it. I'll take a look at Guzzle.

Comment: Found mine in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request2.php